# How to delete a line from a file containing '(' and a variable using bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file named xyz.txt and a varibale delVar=123.
I need to delete a line from xyz.txt having string:

Some (text($delVar

I tried multiple combinations of sed and awk :

```
sed -i "/Some\\\(text\\\($delVar/d" xyz.txt
```

Doesn't work.

```
sed -i '/Some\\(text\\('"$delVar"'/d' xyz.txt
```

Doesn't work either.

When I try to bypass '(' using single \, the error "unmatched ( or (" comes up.

I am using cygwin to run this.

My .sh file:

```
accountId=$1
Number=$2
temp="Example"

grep $temp History.txt > $Number-History.txt
sed -i '/VALUES (CAST('"$accountId"'/d' $Number-History.txt
sed -i '/, CAST('"$accountId"' /!d' $Number-History.txt
sed -i 's/History.txt:/ /' $Number-History.txt
HistCount=$(wc -l < "$Number-History.txt")
echo $HistCount
```

My command:

```
./MyFile.sh 123 ABC000987
```

Here, when I save 123 in accountId and try to set it in my pattern, it matches patters with the number 1234, 1123 etc also

Comment: you don't need to escape the `(`... try `'/Some(text('"$delVar"'/d'`

Comment: @Sundeep , it worked! I guess I was trying too hard :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by Sundeep in a comment, you do not need to escape the `(` because sed by default uses basic regex expressions (where `(` and `+` and others do not need to be escaped to match a literal `(` or `+`, etc.).

But you do need to escape the `$`, because `$` matches the end of the pattern space.

```
sed -i "/Some(text(\$delVar/d" xyz.txt
```

should work.

If you want to use extended regex expressions, use the `-r` flag.

```
sed -ir "/Some\(text\(\$delVar/d" xyz.txt
```

Now you need to escape the `(`s as well as the `$`s.

Comment: I am having an issue with this; sed -i "/Some\(text\(\$delVar/d" xyz.txt is  is not taking the exact match of $delVar. For example, instead of matching only "Some(text(123", it is also matching "Some(text(1234" or "Some(text(0123", where $delVar=123

Comment: @Kritzii Have you tried using `''` quotes instead of `""` quotes?

Comment: @Kritzii `$delvar` is a literal string and not a variable in this subsitution. It will only match `Some(text($delVar`.

Comment: I have tried the following solutions with same result:  "/Some(text(\$delVar/d" xyz.txt  and  '/Some(text('"$delVar"'/d' xyz.txt . Also, I have passed an integer say, 123 in my .sh file and have saved it's value in delVar as delVar=$1. I haven't passed 123 as a string.. Is the issue?

Comment: If `delVar` is a variable, then you use `sed -i "/Some(text($delVar/d" xyz.txt` (don't escape the baskslash).

Comment: Still the same result :(

Comment: @Kritzii I don't think I understand your question correctly then. Could you give the full contents of the bash script as well as `xyz.txt`?

Comment: I have added the file details in my description above now.

Comment: @Kritzii Could you also give an example of what the input file contains?

Comment: quack: The input file contains insert queries to be fed to database. Eg: `INSERT table_name ([id], [name], [accountId]) VALUES (CAST(1 AS Numeric(19, 0)), NULL, CAST(123 AS Numeric(19, 0)))`  I need to pickout and delete certain ones with the matching accountIds

Comment: Try doing `sed -i '/Some(text(\'"$delVar"'\b/d' xyz.txt` (notice the `\b` at the end)

Comment: Still the same.. :P I wonder why it simply isn't accepting just what is given to it when all the characters preceding and proceeding it have explicitly been defined inside quotes.